# GridSearchCV ranking not returning desired values

Tags: machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, gridsearchcv

I am doing a NearestNeighbor recommendation model that takes a list of words and recommend similar words and I want to tune the values for n_neighbors. This is the code I typed out.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

gs_clf = GridSearchCV(NearestNeighbors(algorithm = 'brute'), {
    'n_neighbors': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}, scoring = 'f1', cv=5)

gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(transformed_courses_new , np.array(courses.code))
```

trasnformed_courses_new is a array of shape (159, 120) and np.array(courses.code) is (159,) and each value is an unique label. So my understanding was that the gridsearch will do testing for all the values of n_neighbors and rank the best value of k for which the f1 scoring is maximum. But when I ran the code, I got a warning that NearestNeighbors don't have .predict functionality.

Is there any workaround for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [KNeighborsClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier).

(Keep in mind that kNN suffers from curse of dimensionality.)